# twig if block broken for int 0 comparison. symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Can someone explain why this code outputs false instead of true?
Or is this a bug in twig?

```
{% set key = 0 %}
{% if(key != 'new') %}
    {{'true' }}
{% else %}
    {{ 'false' }}
{% endif %}
```

I use twig in symfony version 2.1.8-dev

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got from github ( https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1079 ) is

Because `key != new` translates to `key != (int) new` not `(bool) key != (bool) new`

And this is actually correct and same behaviour as PHP.

easy solution for this is `{% if(key ~ '' != 'new') %}` and everything works again as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP. You can also have a look to the [comparison with various types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) table to see that if you compare 2 different types from integer, string or reource, the manual says:

> Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math

To convert a string to a number, PHP reads your string from left to right and try to convert it. For example, if your string were `'42new'`, it should have been juggled to `42`. In your case, your string is `'new'`, so PHP just leave it to `0`.

To correct this issue, always compare things of the **same type**, such as, `'0' != 'new'`. Or if you want to have fun, you can create a Twig extension to handle type-strict operators (`===`, `!==`) and you'll not get in trouble anymore.